# How to find a letter in a list of strings with Python

Tags: python

is there a shorter way to write this code?

```
lst = ['Ellie', 'Steve', 'Sam', 'Owen', 'Gavin']
for name in lst:
    if 'A' in name:
        print(name)
    if 'B' in name:
        print(name)
    if 'C' in name:
        print(name)
    if 'D' in name:
        print(name)
    if 'E' in name:
        print(name)
    if 'F' in name:
        print(name)
    if 'G' in name:
        print(name)
    if 'H' in name:
        print(name)
    if 'I' in name:
        print(name)
    if 'J' in name:
        print(name)
    if 'K' in name:
        print(name)
    if 'L' in name:
        print(name)
    if 'M' in name:
        print(name)
```

Essentially what I'm trying to do is to print out every name in the list that begins with the letters A through M

Comment: Don't post images of text, post the text!

Comment: You can add your code here in SO. Just copy & paste it and use the code formatter ("{}" icon". Please see the tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: yes almost certainly ... \

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking to check the initial character is in A-M, then you can use a simple if statement:

```
if name[0] in "ABCDEFGHIJKLM":
    print(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a very simple regular expression:

```
import re
lst = ['Ellie', 'Steve', 'Sam', 'Owen', 'Gavin']
for name in lst:
  if re.search('^[A-M]', name):
    print(name)
```

Also, note that your code does not work as intended, because it will accept the letter in any position, not just the first.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = ["Jonny","Samantha","Frank","Turtle","Robbie","Samuel Jackson"]
print "\n".join(filter(set("ABCDEFGHIJKLM").intersection,lst))
```

is one way to do this

```
import functools
lst = ["Jonny","Samantha","Frank","Turtle","Robbie","Samuel Jackson"]
print "\n".join(filter(functools.partial(re.match,"[A-M]"),lst))
```

is another way that will ensure its only the first letter is a match

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain this question deserves an answer but

```
lst = ['Ellie','Steve','Sam','Owen', 'Gavin', 'Bert', 'coLin', 'ZABCD', 'ellie']
charz = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLM'

for name in lst:
    if any(ch for ch in charz if name.startswith(ch)):
        print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to see if first letter is between `A-M`.

```
import re
lst = ['Ellie', 'Steve', 'Sam', 'Owen', 'Gavin']
for name in lst:
     a = re.compile("^([A-M]).*$")
     if a.match(lst):
          print (name)
```

In the regex, we're basically checking if `lst` matches the pattern of `[A-M]` or `A` through `M` after start of string `^`, followed by `.*`, that matches any characters multiple times(besides for new line) till end of string `$`.

Comment: What version of python are you using that has a switch block?

Comment: You are right. My bad. Python doesn't use switch blocks. Thanks for pointing that out. Took that answer out.